# i can't access my PostgreSQL database from remote server when i am trying to deploy my web app in "pythonanywhare.com"

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, web

When i run my web_app `http://eyobkibret15.pythonanywhere.com/` i get postgresql database connection error like this

"[image: error message]

i have a paid account on the server `pythonanywhere.com`

i try to edit the `pg_hba`  and postgresql configration file inside my postgresql folder and try to add or create a server in pgadmin 4 with my website ip/host but i get this error

```
error saving property 
Unable to connect to server:

timeout expired
```

is there any way to solve the problem ?

Comment: Please post the entire error message.

Comment: Did you configure Postgres to accept network connections?  Is your Postgres server behind a gateway with a firewall?  You'll have to add port forwarding to forward incoming port 5432 to your Postgres server.

Comment: Full error with full traceback could make it possible to help. Maybe paste it as a block, not as a screenshot.